# Executting http request parallel y by using Android Asynchronous Http Client library

Tags: android, http, apache-httpclient-4.x, asynctaskloader, android-async-http

In my android application, I have to get almost 50 data (50 `AsyncTask`) from server  parallel y. So I implemented my logic by using `executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);`. And I read about `executeOnExecutor` which can run only 5 `AsyncTask` at a time and it has a queue of size 10. Where we can keep maximum 10 pending `AyncTask`. Ok, now in my scenario I have 50 `AsyncTask` and I can't execute 50 `AsyncTask` together parallel y because the queue have size only 10. So I can't go with approach of executing 50 `AsyncTask`together.

So I came up with an other logic, there I will create and execute 5 `AyncTask` together. And I will start new `AysncTask` on call back of each already executed `AsyncTask`.

The second logic satisfied my requirement. It is working perfectly.

Note: Here I'm using my own `AsyncTask` class and I'm making http request by using Apache http client.

Now, newly I heard about a library called [android-async-http](https://github.com/loopj/android-async-http). I wanted to reimplement the above logic with this library.

Sample code:

```java
AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
client.get("http://www.google.com", new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(String response) {
        System.out.println(response);
    }
});
```

So my question is,

- How do I execute http request parallel y by using [android-async-http](https://github.com/loopj/android-async-http) library?
- What is the maximum number of `AsyncTask` I can execute parallel y by using this library?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out this library you are using uses a CachedThreadPool:
http://www.blogjava.net/dashi99/archive/2012/08/06/384885.html

Which means that if you execute a lot of requests it will create threads to execute them accordingly. it will reuse threads for the requests if the threads are free and not shut down. So i assume this means that all your requests will run in parallel.